# Broadcast reciever permission denial

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-permissions

I am working on an app where I have to launch a widget when the phone is in call.

I have registered for broadcast request in manifest as such:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
...Other permissions required for screen overlay...
```

I have registered my broadcast receiver in the manifest as such:

```
    <receiver android:name=".phoneReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:enabled="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**Note: I am enabling the receiver at run-time when user presses a button. That is also the time when I am requesting for perms as my test system is running Android 7.0**

I am then requesting permissions at run-time on the press of a button as such:

```
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, 2);
                showToast(getApplicationContext(), "Phone state requested");
            } else{
                enableWidget();    //if permissions are already granted
            }
        }
    });
```

I wait for the result of the permission request as such:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int req, @NonNull String[] perms, @NonNull int[] results){
    switch(req){
        case 2:
            if(results.length > 0 && results[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                showToast(this, "Phone state granted");
                enableWidget();
            }
            return;
    }
}
```

In `enableWidget()`, I enable the broadcast receiver as such:

```
private void enableWidget(){
    PackageManager pm = MainActivity.this.getPackageManager();
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), phoneReceiver.class);
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(comp, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

Now according to me the receiver should be invoked whenever the state is changed but that does not happen. Instead, I get the following in logcat which is making me think that the receiver is enabled but is still not getting called.

```
W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.example.myapplication/.phoneReceiver requires android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE due to sender android (uid 1000)
```

What am I missing here?

---

**PS** Here is a snippet of my Receiver minus the unnecessary stuff:

```
public class phoneReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                return;
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                return;
        }
        if(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)
            .equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
            showToast(context, "In call");
            startWidget(context);
        } else if(intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)
            .equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
            showToast(context, "Out of call");
            stopWidget(context);
        }
    }
    ...Definitions of showToast, start, stopWidget...
}
```

---

**PPS** I checked the app permissions in system settings and "phone" is set to on.

---

I tried keeping the Receiver enabled by default by declaring it in the Manifest as:

```
android:enabled="true"
```

and removing the section for enabling widget at run-time. I am still asking for permissions at run-time. Still I am getting the same error.

The same system, worked on API Level 22.

Answer (score 1):

**Manifest-declared receivers:** If your app targets API level 26 or higher, you **cannot** use the manifest to declare a receiver for implicit broadcasts (broadcasts that do not target your app specifically), except for a few implicit broadcasts that are exempted from that restriction [**Exempted List**](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html). In most cases, you can use scheduled jobs instead.

**Context-registered receivers:** Receive broadcasts as long as their registering context is valid. For an example, if you register within an Activity context, you receive broadcasts as long as the activity is not destroyed. If you register with the Application context, you receive broadcasts as long as the app is running.

Its because of memory improvements check the [**official site**](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts) for further details.

Comment: Right now, my app is targets API level 24. The aim here is just to learn how it works and not to create a production app.

Comment: In simple words you have registered you receiver with valid context to receive data. This process have nothing to do with leaning and production app. check the link for detail.

Comment: Yes but all that is applicable for API level 26 and above right? I am working on level 24

Answer (score -1):

You could use a JobScheduler API to trigger the events , i faced similar issues earlier when i was working with Geofencing API for one of my APP

Comment: I am looking for a solution using the pre-existing android functionalities

Comment: Ok .  I guess this should be correct approach whatever you have done so far. Not sure why this isn't working for you. @ParthK

Comment: Hey were you able to fix this @ParthK